# How to convert RFC3339 format to ISO8601 in golang?

Tags: datetime, go

I have a timestamp which I am getting using `time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)`. The format is `2018-10-17T07:26:33Z` However, I want the format in ISO 8601: `2018-10-17T07:26:33.000Z`

How do I get those extra milliseconds in the end ?

Comment: Use 999 in the format.

Comment: @Volker Can you please help me with exact syntax

Comment: You do `go doc time.RFC3339Nano` and read `go doc time.Format`.

Answer (score 8):

make a custom layout as shown below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t1, e := time.Parse(
        time.RFC3339,
        "2018-10-17T07:26:33Z")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }
    //2018-10-17T07:26:33.000Z required
    //Layouts must use the reference time Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
    fmt.Println(t1.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"))

}
```

playground link (good idea Sunny) https://play.golang.org/p/Y3II7lGZB-D

Answer (score 3):

```
time.Now().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z")
```

Answer (score -3):

use

```
t := time.Now()
var fdatevalue string
// outstr = fmt.Sprintf("%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", t.Month(), t.Day(), t.Hour(),       t.Minute(), t.Second())
fdatevalue=fmt.Sprintf("%02d%02d%2dT%2d:%2d:%2d", t.Year() , t.Month(), t.Day() , t.Hour(),t.Minute(),t.Second)
```